# How can I make Stack call Happy, Alex and other build tools?

Tags: haskell, happy, haskell-stack

As part of my compiler, I need `alex` and `happy` to run as part of my build process. How does Stack support this scenario?

Bonus: how can I register `alex` and `happy` as compile-time dependencies?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`cabal` understand the suffixes `.x` for alex files and `.y` for happy files and will automatically use alex and happy to build the corresponding `.hs` files.

Steps to undertake:

1. Add the `.x` and `.y` files to your `extra-source-files:` section
2. Add `alex` and `happy` to your `build-tools:` section
3. If your source file is `Foo.Bar.x`, make sure that `Foo.Bar` is listed in `exposed-module:` or in `other-modules:`

A good example of a package using alex and happy is the language-python package:

[https://github.com/bjpop/language-python/blob/master/language-python.cabal](https://github.com/bjpop/language-python/blob/916d098a44b8b515ca4a695190b870a5a023d856/language-python.cabal) (permalink)

**Update:** This is relevant to stack as well. In fact, stack will also build alex and happy for you.